# Oracle/SQL - Need query that will select max value from string in each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a graceful way to select the max value from a field holding a comma delimited list.

```
Expected Values:

List_1 | Last
------ | ------
A,B,C  | C   
B,D,C  | D
```

I'm using the following query and I'm not getting what's expected.

```
select
   list_1,
   (
      select max(values) WITHIN GROUP (order by 1) 
      from (
         select
            regexp_substr(list_1,'[^,]+', 1, level) as values
         from dual
         connect by regexp_substr(list_1, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
   ) as last
from my_table
```

Anyone have any ideas to fix my query?

Comment: please tag only the db you are really using ..

Comment: The table is not in **First normal form**, so asking for a "graceful" way to do anything with it may be wishful thinking...

Comment: Are those the only two columns in your table, or do you also have another column that can uniquely identify each row? That can be added on-the-fly, but if it exists already in your data, why not use it and save some execution time?

Comment: @mathguy That's not my full query but I do have a unique identifier in the table.

Comment: @mathguy I basically want to shy away from creating a script that will loop through each row to extract the information I want

Comment: If by "script" and "loop" you mean procedure or function, they are not needed. Something along the lines of what you posted will work. What version of Oracle are you using? See what `select * from v$version` reports, and answer with the full version number (such as 11.2.0.2.0).

Comment: @mathguy My version is 12.1.0.2.0. The query above isn't working and seems to be looking at values from the entire column instead of 1 row. Is there something I should add to the SELECT DUAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     test_data ( id, list_1 ) as (
       select 101, 'A,B,C' from dual union all
       select 102, 'B,D,C' from dual union all
       select 105, null    from dual union all
       select 122, 'A'     from dual union all
       select 140, 'A,B,B' from dual
     )
-- end of simulated table (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution)
select   id, list_1, max(token) as max_value
from     ( select id, list_1, 
                  regexp_substr(list_1, '([^,])(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as token
           from   test_data
           connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(list_1, ',')                  
                  and prior id = id
                  and prior sys_guid() is not null
         )
group by id, list_1
order by id
;

  ID LIST_1_ MAX_VAL
---- ------- -------
 101 A,B,C   C    
 102 B,D,C   D    
 105            
 122 A       A    
 140 A,B,B   B
```

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, this can be re-written using the `LATERAL` clause:

```
select   d.id, d.list_1, x.max_value
from     test_data d,
         lateral ( select max(regexp_substr(list_1, '([^,]*)(,|$)',
                                            1, level, null, 1)) as max_value
                   from   test_data x
                   where  x.id = d.id
                   connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(list_1, ',')
                 ) x
order by d.id
;
```